# Microsoft chart control zoom out and panning

Tags: mschart

I have been playing with Ms chart control zoom feature. One thing I have not been able to do is to do Zoom out. Although we can Zoom in, there is not Zoom out feature. I could only reset the zoom that is not what i am looking for. 
Any one here who has done Zoom out for MS hart controls?? Any suggestions.
Also any pointers to how to implement panning for Ms charts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The zoom out is done one the axis scrollbar!
Also there is nothing to stop you setting the zoom diagrammatically:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(-10, 110);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(-10, 20);
```

the values you enter there can be outside the min/max of the data.

Comment: thanks Dominique. The zoom out on axis scrollbar is zoom reset, not exactly the zoom out thing i am looking for. but yes i can do it programmatically as well. Also, how do i pan the chart using some sort of hand tool?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hand tool, but I think ScaleView is also what is needed: 
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(increment)

Answer (score 1):

I started to write a [helper for MS Charts controls](https://bitbucket.org/grumly57/mschartfriend). It includes mouse based scrolling and a mousewheel zoom.
It is very simple you can tweak it for your own needs very quickly. It does not use viewmin and viewmax and can zoom out as far as you wish.

Comment: There is something similar available on NuGet : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376059/MSChart-Extension-Zoom-and-Pan-Controls