# .NET Chart set minimum length for scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I am working on an application that is using the Winforms chart control.

I have the width of the chart form set (in terms of pixel size) , and I would like to set a value to determine when to enable the scrollbar for the X axis on the chart. For example, within the visible range of the chart I would like there to be 100 "ticks" on the X axis, instead of cramming all 10,000 of them onto the chart.

Is there a way to set this?

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF?

Comment: I'm hosting a Winform in a WPF application

Comment: @VRKnight, I have removed the irrelevant [tag:WPF] tag and replaced it with the more accurate [tag:Winforms] tag as your problem resides in the `Winforms` part of your application.

Comment: I think you need to set the width programmatically some where with in your databound event of the series.. (also the scale)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft chart control zoom out and panning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921045/microsoft-chart-control-zoom-out-and-panning)